# Remove transparent hole behind TextSpan?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a background color to a textspan as I dont want to use container for this but a transparent hole is coming from nowhere. How do i solve it?

My code is

```
RichText(
              text: TextSpan(text: 'TEST: ', children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'HELLO',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      background: Paint()
                        ..color = Colors.red
                        ..strokeWidth = 10
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              ]),
            )
```

It is the child of a container whose color is green.

I am getting output as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSvVm.jpg) behind text "Hello".

How do I make the red color opaque?

Comment: Can you show the complete code of the parent containing this RichText, because what I see is there is a border covering the "Hello" text

Answer (score 0):

use `PaintingStyle.fill` instead of stroke or increase the strokeWidth until the hole disappear

```
RichText(
                text: TextSpan(text: 'TEST: ', children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'HELLO',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        background: Paint()
                          ..color = Colors.red
                          ..strokeWidth = 10
                          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
```

Comment: That works but It is now same height and width as the text. How do add padding like look to the text HELLO –

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **strokeWidth** and replace **PaintingStyle.stroke** by **PaintingStyle.fill** and it will be good.

```
 RichText(text: TextSpan(text: 'TEST: ', 
       children: [
           TextSpan(
                text: 'HELLO',
                 style: TextStyle(
                    background: Paint()
                      ..color = Colors.red
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
         ]),
        ),
```

Comment: That works but It is now same height and width as the text. How do add padding like look to the text HELLO